# MS-Access : How to sum multiple values from 2 different tables according to dates with output on 1 date per row

Tags: ms-access

I am still getting started learning Access.

I have 3 tables.  Table one has Date as primary key and will have all dates.  Tables 2 and 3 (**Table 3 is mislabeled in the example image as a second Table 2**) will both have 2 columns, Date and Amount.  Tables 2 and 3 could have multiple rows with the same date (different amounts) and some may miss dates.  I am looking for an output query that would have 1 row for every date in table 2 & 3 that has an amount (some dates may not have an amount in either table) and sums all those amounts for that date in 1 row.  Below are example tables and the desired output query.  Thanks so much for the newbie help!

[image: Cant post pics yet so CLICK HERE FOR EXAMPLE]

I now have this code **(Note that I have eliminated Table 1)**:

```
SELECT Table2.Dat, Sum(Table2.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount], Sum(Table2.Tax) AS [Sum Of Tax]
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.Dat;

UNION ALL SELECT Table3.Dat, Sum(Table3.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount], Sum(Table3.Tax) AS [Sum Of Tax]
FROM Table3
GROUP BY Table3.Dat;
```

This sums the amounts from same dates for each seperate table, but does not sum the dates for both tables.  I imagine it is another GROUP function but I have not been successful in forming it correctly.

***Current Results from code above***

[image]

Comment: You need to do a `UNION ALL` of tables 2 and 3, then `SUM(Amount)` and `GROUP BY Date`.

Comment: Table 1 seems irrelevant, since your output doesn't have all dates, only the dates that are in tables 2 and 3.

Comment: I think `Table1` is not considerable here. Make a `UNION` query from `Table2` and `Table3`. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, sorry I didnt put this question together properly!  I will do my best to continue to learn the correct procedure as I move forward and improve.

Comment: I removed Table 1 (that only had dates) and now have Table 1 and Table 2 that have different dates and amounts.  This is the code I now have but the only thing it is not doing is combining all "Sums" into one Date row for each date.  Hopefully I am close?


SELECT Table1.Dat, Sum(Table1.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount], Sum(Table1.Tax) AS [Sum Of Tax]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Dat;

UNION ALL SELECT Table2.Dat, Sum(Table2.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount], Sum(Table2.Tax) AS [Sum Of Tax]
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.Dat;

Comment: @David you are very near to your desired output. Did you try my answer?

Comment: @Harun24HR Yes, desired output is close!  I just saw your answer and tried it out, but it did not work for me.  It is asking for 3 parameter inputs when I run the query for:Table 1.tDate, tDate, Table 2.tDate.  Again, excuse my ignorance here but not sure why it is asking for that?  Goal is for it to just run and sum for all data in both tables with no user input required.  When I do input a date for those inputs, I get 1 result on 1 row.  Please let me know what I may be missing to get all results?

Comment: Those are table fields in my database. So, you have to change tDate, Amount in my code with your table field name.

Comment: @Harun24HR Thanks for bearing with me on this and pardon my newbieness again!  Output now matches and am very grateful for the help. :)  One last question, it looks as thought his creates a table "tt"?  But that table does not show up under the Access objects or relationships.  Is it basically a temporary table?  Just wanted to understand the mechanics so I can continue to learn.  Many thanks!

Comment: It do not create any table. Basically it calls assigning a ALIAS named tt of UNION query and use that alias for further operation. If the code works then consider accepting the answer. Tick mark the answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query.

```
SELECT tt.mDate AS TransactionDate, Sum(tt.SumOfAmount) AS AmountTotal
FROM (SELECT Table2.tDate as mDate, Sum(Table2.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM Table2
GROUP BY tDate

UNION

SELECT Table3.tDate As mDate, Sum(Table3.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM Table3
GROUP BY tDate)  AS tt
GROUP BY tt.mDate;
```

[image]